# how to getselected string spinner another class

Tags: android, string, if-statement, spinner, android-spinner

how to retrieve the selected string in another class

toast and show if there is a choice the same string

declaration is included in the button script set.OnCLick ...

usig if else

```
if (
 getString(R.id.spin1, equals("Book") == 
 getString(R.id.spin2, equals("Book")){
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     `enter code here`
}
```

spin1 is spinner from class A and spin2 is Spinner from class B, but this but the script is not the way?? please help me....???

Comment: please clearify what you want... This Code above is complete senseless. if `getString()` is the one from Activity, it shouldn't take R.ID. but takes usuallay R.STRING. The second Argument is for formatting, while `equals()` usually returned a boolean value (But I cannot see Which object should be equal to book). Everyone has to guess what you want to do. If you wanna set the String to a Class simply add a Setter for it, and for an Activity you can post additional Infos inside the Intent, you use to start it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared preferences for storing and retrieving values :

simple demo to store value is

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
```

for more information check this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html